# Was trying to show the ambient temparature inside the textView, but onSensorChanged method is not working, its not setting the text of textview

Tags: java, android-studio

I am trying to show results in text view but it's not showing temperature in text view. My device has a sensor,when I set text through the if statement inside oncreate it works. It's just onSensorchanged that is not working, even tried to make toast inside the onSensorChanged but it's not working.
package com.example.lab4sensor;

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener {
    private TextView txtview;
    private SensorManager sensormanager;
    private Sensor sensOR;
   private  boolean sensorAvailable;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txtview = findViewById(R.id.txtTemp);
        sensormanager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

        if(sensormanager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE)!=null){
            sensOR = sensormanager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE);
            //txtview.setText("set temp");
            sensorAvailable = true;

        }else{
            txtview.setText("Temparature Sensor is not available");
            sensorAvailable = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {

            txtview.setText(sensorEvent.values[0]+" °C");


    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(sensorAvailable = true){
            sensormanager.registerListener(this,sensOR,SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this,"Not available",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if(sensorAvailable =true){
            sensormanager.unregisterListener(this);
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTemp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```